# Pasar parametros en una funcion JAVA

Tags: java

estoy creando este menu, y lo que busco es que cuando de click en "clientes", me habra la ventana de "cliente"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este seria mi codigo:

```
private void Menu_clienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    ingresar_pagina();
} 

public void ingresar_pagina(){
                cliente abrir =new cliente();
                abrir.setVisible(true);
}
```

pero como tengo muchas ventanas, tendria que crear muchas funciones como "ingresar pagina()". como haria para pasar un parametro por ingresar_pagina() para llamar siempre a esa funcion. osea algo asi:

```
private void Menu_clienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    ingresar_pagina("cliente");
} 

public void ingresar_pagina(String recibir_variable){
                recibir_variable abrir =new recibir_variable();
                abrir.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes pasarle al método `ingresar_pagina()` la clase de la ventana que deseas abrir y utilizando API Reflección crear una instancia de esta y luego llamar el método `setVisible`.

Algo como esto:

```
    private void Menu_clienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        ingresar_pagina(MiVentana.class);
    }

    public <T extends java.awt.Window> void ingresar_pagina(Class<T> claseVentana){
        newInstanceOf(claseVentana)
                .ifPresent(v -> v.setVisible(true));
    }

    public <T extends java.awt.Window> Optional<T> newInstanceOf(Class<T> clazz) {
        Constructor constructor = null;

        try {
            constructor = clazz.getConstructor();
            return Optional.of((T) constructor.newInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Hacer algo

            // Aquí pueden ser lanzadas las siguientes excepciones:
            // - NoSuchMethodException: Si no se encuentra un constructor sin parámetros
            // - InstantiationException: Si la clase sobre la que se invoca el constructor es abstracta
            // - IllegalAccessException: El constructor no es accesible
            // - InvocationTargetException: Si la llamada al constructor lanza una excepción
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
```